# zapier oauth2 giving error for access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, zapier, zapier-cli

Hi i am trying to implement oauth2 with Zapier platform, and i am facing some error.
I just have a testing node.js app where i am login request from zapier platform.

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let count = 0;

// const redirect url = https://zapier.com/dashboard/auth/oauth/return/App77581CLIAPI/

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({
    count
}));


app.post('/zapier', (req, res) => {
    count++;
    res.json({
        count
    })
})

app.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    // console.log('req', req);

    const { state } = req.query;
    // const state = 1578212496.13945431311;
    console.log(state);
    const user = {
        name: "ankit",
        id: 12344
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(user, "luciferTonify");

    const code = uuidv4();
    res.redirect(`https://zapier.com/dashboard/auth/oauth/return/App77581CLIAPI?code=${code}&state=${state}&access_token=${code}&token_type=bearer`);

})

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        name: "ankit",
        id: 12344
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(user, "luciferTonify");

    res.json({ token });

});

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const { authorization: token } = req.headers;
    if (typeof token == 'undefined' || !token) {
        req.token = token;
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(403);
    }
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

its just a testing app, so i am trying to send an access_token, but zapier is giving me this error

**

> Zapier could not connect to your account. Field named `access_token`
>   not found in OAuth2 results

**
?
can anyone help me what i am doing wrong ?